# Order search results in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

When using [react-select](https://react-select.com/home), search results are ordered alphabetically by default. This is a good default but not so nice if I have an exact match that is not first alphabetically. For example, a user may have the following options:

- a_react
- b_react
- c_react
- d_react
- react

With these options, the user may search for 'react' and not be any closer to selecting the option that exactly matches the search term. Is there any way to optimize for exact matches?

Comment: you can pass your own `filterOption` to change how the filtering happens

Comment: @JohnRuddell ah nice, I searched the docs for "search" and "results" but didn't find anything there, good find. I found [this example](https://github.com/henryksloan/bing-schedules/blob/bf2c2752ccba86d888f1da431f7f0bf50a3994e8/src/components/CourseSelector.js#L60) but any other examples are helpful. Feel free to change this to an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: It looks like that particular example is exactly what you want! :) I'll write up an answer about the `filterOption` so we can close out the question :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`react-select` has a prop if you want to have a custom filter - `filterOption`.

If you want to show better matches based on what a user queries, use [match-sorter](https://github.com/kentcdodds/match-sorter) in combination with `onInputChange` of `react-select` to create a custom filter. Here's a [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-select-match-sorter).

There are two select inputs. Type `l` and observe the difference in suggestions.

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure if it will work with `react-select`. I couldn't find any examples on Github of the two playing nicely together.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working demo. I should have been clearer. `filterOption` would have nothing to do with that. `onInputChange` and `matchSorter`  can be combined to achieve that.

Comment: It seems inadvisable to circumvent the intended prop for this, `filterOption`. It seems like passing a new options object might break built-in optimizations.

Comment: @Slbox You could be right. However, there's no such warnings in `react-select` docs. And since `onInputChange` is a prop that's exposed, I just see it as one deeper level of customization for those who want to take further control of filtering.

Answer (score 10):

In `react-select` you can pass a `filterOption` property to change how the filtering works. They provide a nice api to do what you want, which is start matching from the beginning of the string rather than anywhere in the string. That would look something like this

```
filterOption={createFilter({ matchFrom: "start" })}
```

where `createFilter` is imported from `react-select`

Comment: i am using this with CreatableSelect and its not letting me create new options

Answer (score 2):

@ron4ex has a great answer here. Just wanted to offer another similar solution as I had 1 big issue with match-sorter.

Issue with [match-sorter](https://github.com/kentcdodds/match-sorter):

- My list is a list of family relationships, e.g. "mother", "mother-in-law"
- match-sorter would prioritize mother-in-law over mother as I started typing. Only once it was a full match would it prioritize mother. However, react-select kept the focused option as mother-in-law.
- Even if I could fix the default focus issue, I would rather "mot" match to "mother" before "mother-in-law".

Enter new solution: [Fuse](https://github.com/krisk/fuse):

- Similar implementation as match-sorter
- Fuzzy search with lots of customization options
- Default config sorted "mother" over "mother-in-law"

```js
const fuse = new Fuse(relationshipTypes, { keys: ["label"] });

<Select>
  onInputChange={inputValue => {
    setRelationshipOptions(
      fuse.search(inputValue).map(value => value.item)
    );
  }}
</Select>
```

- notice the map on fuse.search as fuse returns a mutated array with the original values in an item key and a second key being the index. Hence, fuse.search().map

Comment: This worked really nicely for me