# React-select is going blank when the options array changes (codesandbox included)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use react-select in combination with match-sorter as described in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57191622/order-search-results-in-react-select) ([their working version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-select-match-sorter)). I have an initial array of objects that get mapped to an array of objects with the `value` and `label` properties required by react-select, which is stored in state. That array is passed directly to react-select, and when you first click the search box everything looks good, all the options are there. The onInputChange prop is given a call to matchSorter, which in turn is given the array, the new input value, and the key the objects should be sorted on. In my project, and reproduced in the sandbox, as soon as you type anything into the input field, all the options disappear and are replaced by the `no options` message. If you click out of the box and back into it, the sorted options show up the way they should. See [my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-match-sorter-nc8h0?file=/src/App.js:0-700) for the issue, and here's the sandbox code:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { matchSorter } from "match-sorter";
import { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const objs = [
  { name: "hello", id: 1 },
  { name: "world", id: 2 },
  { name: "stack", id: 3 },
  { name: "other", id: 4 },
  { name: "name", id: 5 }
];

const myMapper = (obj) => {
  return {
    value: obj.id,
    label: <div>{obj.name}</div>,
    name: obj.name
  };
};

export default function App() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(objs.map((obj) => myMapper(obj)));
  return (
    <Select
      options={options}
      onInputChange={(val) => {
        setOptions(matchSorter(options, val, { keys: ["name", "value"] }));
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

I am sure that the array in state is not getting removed or anything, I've console logged each step of the way and the array is definitely getting properly sorted by match-sorter. It's just that as soon as you type anything, react-select stops rendering any options until you click out and back in again. Does it have something to do with using JSX as the `label` value? I'm doing that in my project in order to display an image along with the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do two things to make your code work:

1. Replaced `label: <div>{obj.name}</div>` with `label: obj.name` in your mapper function.

   I am not sure if **react-select** allows html nodes as labels. Their [documentation](https://react-select.com/props) just defines it as `type OptionType = { [string]: any }` which is way too generic for anything.
2. The list supplied to `matchSorter` for *matching* must be the full list (with all options). You were supplying the filtered list of previous match (from component's state).

```
const objs = [
  { name: "hello", id: 1 },
  { name: "world", id: 2 },
  { name: "stack", id: 3 },
  { name: "other", id: 4 },
  { name: "name", id: 5 }
];

const myMapper = (obj) => {
  return {
    value: obj.id,
    label: obj.name, // -------------------- (1)
    name: obj.name
  };
};

const allOptions = objs.map((obj) => myMapper(obj));

export default function App() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(allOptions);
  return (
    <Select
      options={options}
      onInputChange={(val) => {
        setOptions(
          matchSorter(
            allOptions, // ----------------> (2)
            val,
            { keys: ["name", "value"]
          }
        ));
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, I believe the problem was trying to use html as a label directly. I had to slightly modify the `myMapper` function and was then able to instead pass it as the `formatOptionLabel` prop on the `Select` component, which is I believe the proper way to do what I was trying to do.